# Disable print() in Dart

Tags: dart

Is there a way to disable the print function Dart code or somehow intercept it?
Some devs on our team keep on using print instead of the logger we built which means we see a lot of garbage in the console that we have no way of switching off unless we do a search replace through all the code to find 
and replace `print(String)` with `log.info(String)`

Ideally we should be using a pre-commit hook to check if the committed code contains prints and then reject the commit, but it seems quicker to just block the print at code-level.

```
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

part of dart.core;

/// Prints a string representation of the object to the console.
void print(Object object) {
  String line = "$object";
  if (printToZone == null) {
    printToConsole(line);
  } else {
    printToZone(line);
  }
}
```

`print` is part of `dart.core`, is it possible to override anything in `dart.core` either via code or via some transformer in `pubspec.yaml`?

If not, I guess it's time to go setup that pre-commit hook.

Comment: Ideally team management should flex their muscles a bit to tell the devs to cut it out. That's behavior better addressed with the devs than some sort of technical solution.

Comment: it's a startup, so no control structures yet, just devs all adding code to an enormous code-base. Those who do use prints, have all been told not to do it, but still forget some days, then all of a sudden you see 100s of fresh prints in the code-base print stuff to the console and you have no idea where it's coming from, unless you go and search the code-base. It's more of an annoyance that I'm hoping to squash by replacing print with something that just prints nothing and reminds the user to use log.info/debug/danger/warn instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best solution will be a linter rule like https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/88

In the meantime you can run code in a new zone and override the print method there

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/ZoneSpecification-class.html

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/Zone/print.html

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/PrintHandler.html

http://jpryan.me/dartbyexample/examples/zones/

> ```
> import 'dart:async';
>
> main() {
>   // All Dart programs implicitly run in a root zone.
>   // runZoned creates a new zone.  The new zone is a child of the root zone.
>   runZoned(() async {
>     await runServer();
>   },
>   // Any uncaught errors in the child zone are sent to the [onError] handler.
>       onError: (e, stacktrace) {
>     print('caught: $e');
>   },
>   // a ZoneSpecification allows for overriding functionality, like print()
>     zoneSpecification: new ZoneSpecification(print: (Zone self, ZoneDelegate parent, Zone zone, String message) {
>       parent.print(zone, '${new DateTime.now()}: $message');
>     })
>   );
> }
> ```

And to hide print in release mode

```
main() {
   runZonedGuarded(() {
   runApp(MyApp());
 }, (error, stackTrace) {
   print(stackTrace);
 }, zoneSpecification: new ZoneSpecification(
     print: (Zone self, ZoneDelegate parent, Zone zone, String message){
   // parent.print(zone, '${new DateTime.now()}: $message');
   /**
    * Print only in debug mode
    * */
   if (kDebugMode) {
     parent.print(zone, message);
   }
 }));
}
```

Comment: This is pretty neat, I just added my Angular bootstrapping code into the runZoned section and made the ZoneSpecification not display anything in the console and voila, clean console logs! Thanks for this Gunter!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer does `runZoned` cause any performance impacts? As far as I undertand we will be wrapping the root zone in a new zone, so I know know how this wrapping interacts and affects our code.

Comment: No, you can safely ignore the performance impact if you are not working on code where you count individual CPU cycles.

Comment: What do you mean by counting CPU cycles? Does it affect Timers then?

Comment: No I meant where performance requirements are so high you need to tweak code to save one more CPU cycle :D

Comment: In case of Flutter, I don't think we need to add `async` since `runApp()` doesn't need any `await`.